# How can I compute the probability at a point given a normal distribution in Perl?

Tags: perl, r, statistics, probability

Is there a package in Perl that allows you to compute the height of probability distribution at each given point. For example this can be done in R this way:

```
> dnorm(0, mean=4,sd=10)
> 0.03682701
```

Namely the probability of point x=0 falls into a normal distribution, with mean=4 and sd=10, is 0.0368.
I looked at [Statistics::Distribution](http://search.cpan.org/~mikek/Statistics-Distributions-1.02/Distributions.pm) but it doesn't give that very 
function to do it.

Comment: the probability of any point in a normal distribution is of course zero. what are you trying to calculate?

Comment: @EL: I don't mean "any/random" but a "given" point.

Comment: normal is continuous, so the probability of any point (given or not) is zero. maybe you want the density? (that's what "d" stands for in dnorm.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not something along these lines (I am writing in R, but it could be done in  perl with  Statistics::Distribution):

```
dn <- function(x=0 # value
               ,mean=0 # mean 
               ,sd=1 # sd
               ,sc=10000 ## scale the precision
               ) {
  res <- (pnorm(x+1/sc, mean=mean, sd=sd)-pnorm(x, mean=mean, sd=sd))*sc
  res
}
> dn(0,4,10,10000)
0.03682709
> dn(2.02,2,.24)
1.656498
```

[edit:1] I should mention that this approximation can get pretty horrible at the far tails. it might  or might not matter depending on your application.

[edit:2] @foolishbrat Turned the code into a function. The result should always be positive. Perhaps you are forgetting that in the perl module you mention the function returns the upper probability 1-F, and R returns F?

[edit: 3] fixed a copy and paste error.

Comment: @EL: Thanks. How would you adjust your approach, when the final result is negative. For example, x=2.02, mean=2, sd=0.24. Your approach would give -2.880624e-05.

Comment: @EL: In your last example. My machine gives different result: dn(2.02,2,.24); [1] 1.656469. I am using R version 2.9.2.

Comment: @foolishbrat: it was my mistake. ~1.65 is correct. (and agrees with the answer from dnorm.) sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @EL: What do people do usually when dnorm is greater than 1 like the example?

Comment: @foolishbrat: Again, I think you are confusing probability (which is bounded between 0 and 1) with probability density (which is not). Like others pointed out, you probably want the cumulative distribution function; but there is no way for us to know it since you haven't told us what you want to do. You should also consult a intro to statistics book.

Answer (score 8):

dnorm(0, mean=4, sd=10) does *not* give you thr probability of such a point occurring. To quote Wikipedia on [probability density function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function)

> In probability theory, a probability
>   density function (pdf)—often referred
>   to as a probability distribution
>   function[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function)—or density, of a random
>   variable is a function that describes
>   the density of probability at each
>   point in the sample space. The
>   probability of a random variable
>   falling within a given set is given by
>   the integral of its density over the
>   set.

and the probability you mention is

```
R> pnorm(0, 4, 10)
[1] 0.3446
```

or a 34.46% chance of getting a value equal to or smaller than 0 from a N(4, 10) distribution.

As for your Perl question:  If you know how to do it in R, but need it from Perl, maybe you need to write a Perl extension based on R's libRmath (provided in Debian by the package r-mathlib) to get those functions to Perl?  This does not require the R interpreter.

Otherwise, you could try the GNU GSL or the Cephes libraries for access to these special functions.

Comment: There's already a module on CPAN that can use R. It's a mess, but I could get it to work in the past: http://search.cpan.org/~gmpassos/Statistics-R-0.02/

Comment: the distribution function (like pnorm) in Statistics::Distributions is uprob. 1-uprob((0-4)/10) should give you ~ 0.34 (I don't have it installed to confirm this.) I doesn't have the density function, though.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want the density function, why not use it directly:

```
$pi = 3.141593;
$x = 2.02;
$mean = 2;
$sd = .24;
print 1/($sd * sqrt(2*$pi)) * exp(-($x-$mean)**2 / (2 * $sd**2));
```

It gives 1.65649768474891 about the same as dnorm in R.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Jouni is quite right.  This seems to give a reasonable version of the PDF (extract the middle of the loop if you just want a specific x-y point):

```
!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Getopt::Std;
use POSIX qw(ceil floor);

# Usage
# Outputs normal density function given a mean and sd
# -s standard deviation
# -m mean
# -n normalization factor (multiply result by this amount), optional

my %para = ();
getopts('s:m:n:', \%para);
if (!exists ($para{'s'}) || !exists ($para{'m'})) {
   die ("mean and standard deviation required");
}

my $norm = 1.0;
if (exists ($para{'n'})) {
   $norm = $para{'n'};
}

my $sd = $para{'s'};
my $mean = $para{'m'};

my $start = floor($mean - ($sd * 5));
my $end = ceil($mean + ($sd * 5));

my $pi = 3.141593;

my $var = $sd**2;

for (my $x = $start; $x < $end; $x+=0.1) {
    my $e = exp( -1 * (($x-$mean)**2) / (2*$var));
    my $d = sqrt($var) * sqrt(2*$pi);
    my $y = 1.0/$d*$e * $norm;
    printf ("%5.5f %5.5f\n", $x, $y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you probably want the cumulative distribution function. This can be obtained via the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) (shifted by the mean and scaled by the standard deviation of your normal distribution), which exists in the standard math library and is made accessible in Perl by [Math::Libm](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math::Libm).

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl's Statistics::Distributions, you can achieve this with:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Statistics::Distributions qw(uprob);

my $x       = 0;
my $mean    = 4;
my $stdev   = 10;

print "Height of probablility distribution at point $x = "
    . (1-uprob(($x-$mean)/$stdev))."\n";
```

Results with "Height of probablility distribution at point 0 = 0.34458"

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do the same thing you're doing with R in Perl using the [Math::SymbolicX::Statistics::Distributions](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Math-SymbolicX-Statistics-Distributions/lib/Math/SymbolicX/Statistics/Distributions.pm) module from CPAN:

```
use strict; use warnings;

use Math::SymbolicX::Statistics::Distributions qw/normal_distribution/;

my $norm = normal_distribution(qw/mean sd/);
print $norm->value(mean => 4, sd => 10, x => 0), "\n";

# curry it with the parameter values
$norm->implement(mean => 4, sd => 10);
print $norm->value(x => 0),"\n"; # prints the same as above
```

The normal_distribution() function from that module is a generator for functions. $norm will be a [Math::Symbolic](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Math-Symbolic/lib/Math/Symbolic.pm) (::Operator) object that you can modify. For example with *implement*, which, in the above example, replaces the two parameter variables with constants.

Note, however as Dirk pointed out, that you probably want the cumulative function of the normal distribution. Or more generally the integral in a certain range.

Unfortunately, Math::Symbolic can't do integration symbolically. Therefore, you'd have to resort to numerical integration with the likes of [Math::Integral::Romberg](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Math-Integral-Romberg/lib/Math/Integral/Romberg.pm). (Alternatively, search CPAN for an implementation of the error function.) This may be slow, but it's still easy to do. Add this to the above snippet:

```
use Math::Integral::Romberg 'integral';

my ($int_sub) = $norm->to_sub(); # compile to a faster Perl sub
print $int_sub->(0),"\n";  # same number as above

print "p=" . integral($int_sub, -100., 0) . "\n";
# -100 is an arbitrary, small number
```

This should give you the ~0.344578258389676 from Dirk's answer.