# How to calculate probability in a normal distribution given mean & standard deviation?

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, probability

How to calculate probability in normal distribution given mean, std in Python? I can always explicitly code my own function according to the definition like the OP in this question did: [Calculating Probability of a Random Variable in a Distribution in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448246/calculating-probability-of-a-random-variable-in-a-distribution-in-python)

Just wondering if there is a library function call will allow you to do this. In my imagine it would like this:

```
nd = NormalDistribution(mu=100, std=12)
p = nd.prob(98)
```

There is a similar question in Perl: [How can I compute the probability at a point given a normal distribution in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377003/how-can-i-compute-the-probability-at-a-point-given-a-normal-distribution-in-perl). But I didn't see one in Python.

`Numpy` has a `random.normal` function, but it's like sampling, not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

There's one in [scipy.stats](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html):

```
>>> import scipy.stats
>>> scipy.stats.norm(0, 1)
<scipy.stats.distributions.rv_frozen object at 0x928352c>
>>> scipy.stats.norm(0, 1).pdf(0)
0.3989422804014327
>>> scipy.stats.norm(0, 1).cdf(0)
0.5
>>> scipy.stats.norm(100, 12)
<scipy.stats.distributions.rv_frozen object at 0x928352c>
>>> scipy.stats.norm(100, 12).pdf(98)
0.032786643008494994
>>> scipy.stats.norm(100, 12).cdf(98)
0.43381616738909634
>>> scipy.stats.norm(100, 12).cdf(100)
0.5
```

[One thing to beware of -- just a tip -- is that the parameter passing is a little broad.  Because of the way the code is set up, if you accidentally write `scipy.stats.norm(mean=100, std=12)` instead of `scipy.stats.norm(100, 12)` or `scipy.stats.norm(loc=100, scale=12)`, then it'll accept it, but silently discard those extra keyword arguments and give you the default (0,1).]

Comment: How would you get probabilities from ranges? Say from 98 - 102?

Comment: @DSM: In your above example, when you say `scipy.stats.norm(100, 12).pdf(98)`, does that mean the probability of getting 98 in a distribution with `mean 100 `and `stddev 12` is `0.032` ?

Comment: @ThePredator: no, the probability of getting 98 in a normal distribution with mean 100 and stddev 12 is zero. :-)  The probability *density* is 0.032.

Comment: Probability density in that case means the y-value, given the x-value 1.42 for the normal distribution. cdf means what we refer to as the area under the curve.

Comment: @Leon, that's `rv.cdf(102) - rv.cdf(98)` where `rv = scipy.stats.norm(100, 12)`.

Comment: @DSM Hi. Can we also call this Likelihood of (mean=100, stddev=12|x=98)?

Answer (score 61):

Scipy.stats is a great module. Just to offer another approach, you can calculate it directly using

```
import math
def normpdf(x, mean, sd):
    var = float(sd)**2
    denom = (2*math.pi*var)**.5
    num = math.exp(-(float(x)-float(mean))**2/(2*var))
    return num/denom
```

This uses the formula found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Probability_density_function

to test:

```
>>> normpdf(7,5,5)  
0.07365402806066466
>>> norm(5,5).pdf(7)
0.073654028060664664
```

Comment: Hey, this is a really nice answer. Would you mind providing a step-by step explanation, perhaps?

Comment: This method needs less computation time than scipy

Comment: But scipy can handle arrays of means, stdevs and samples:

   mean   = [ 5, 10, 20]
   stddev = [20, 30, 40]
   for x in (
         [ 5, 10, 20],
         [10, 20, 40],
         [15, 30, 50],
         ):
      prob = scipy.stats.norm(mean, stddev).cdf(x)
      print(f'prob = {prob}')

outputs:

    prob = [0.5 0.5 0.5]
    prob = [0.59870633 0.63055866 0.69146246]
    prob = [0.69146246 0.74750746 0.77337265]

Answer (score 48):

Here is [more info](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html).
First you are dealing with a frozen distribution (frozen in this case means its parameters are set to specific values). To create a frozen distribution:

```
import scipy.stats
scipy.stats.norm(loc=100, scale=12)
#where loc is the mean and scale is the std dev
#if you wish to pull out a random number from your distribution
scipy.stats.norm.rvs(loc=100, scale=12)

#To find the probability that the variable has a value LESS than or equal
#let's say 113, you'd use CDF cumulative Density Function
scipy.stats.norm.cdf(113,100,12)
Output: 0.86066975255037792
#or 86.07% probability

#To find the probability that the variable has a value GREATER than or
#equal to let's say 125, you'd use SF Survival Function 
scipy.stats.norm.sf(125,100,12)
Output: 0.018610425189886332
#or 1.86%

#To find the variate for which the probability is given, let's say the 
#value which needed to provide a 98% probability, you'd use the 
#PPF Percent Point Function
scipy.stats.norm.ppf(.98,100,12)
Output: 124.64498692758187
```

Comment: I can't thank enough whoever wrote this answer. I was looking everywhere to solve this but couldn't able to find it. And adding the comments with the code really helped me understand what is happening. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just want to ask one question, how to calculate these probabilities when the data is not normally distributed? What I have to do in this case?

Answer (score 31):

Starting `Python 3.8`, the standard library provides the [`NormalDist`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html?highlight=normaldist#statistics.NormalDist) object as part of the [`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html) module.

It can be used to get the ***probability density function*** ([`pdf`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html#statistics.NormalDist.pdf) - likelihood that a random sample X will be near the given value x) for a given *mean* (`mu`) and *standard deviation* (`sigma`):

```
from statistics import NormalDist

NormalDist(mu=100, sigma=12).pdf(98)
# 0.032786643008494994
```

Also note that the `NormalDist` object also provides the ***cumulative distribution function*** (`cdf` - probability that a random sample X will be less than or equal to x):

```
NormalDist(mu=100, sigma=12).cdf(98)
# 0.43381616738909634
```

Comment: This is the best answer because it uses the native library. Not everyone wants to use scipy

Answer (score 12):

In case you would like to find the area between 2 values of x mean = 1;  standard deviation = 2; the probability of x between [0.5,2]

```
import scipy.stats
scipy.stats.norm(1, 2).cdf(2) - scipy.stats.norm(1,2).cdf(0.5)
```

Comment: Thanks - this formula is very hard to find online, but very useful.

Answer (score 6):

Note that **probability** is different than **probability density** `pdf()`, which some of the previous answers refer to. *Probability* is the chance that the variable has a specific value, whereas the *probability density* is the chance that the variable will be near a specific value, meaning probability over a range. So to obtain the probability you need to compute the integral of the probability density function over a given interval. As an approximation, you can simply multiply the probability density by the interval you're interested in and that will give you the actual probability.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

data_start = -10
data_end = 10
data_points = 21
data = np.linspace(data_start, data_end, data_points)

point_of_interest = 5
mu = np.mean(data)
sigma = np.std(data)                                   
interval = (data_end - data_start) / (data_points - 1)
probability = norm.pdf(point_of_interest, loc=mu, scale=sigma) * interval
```

The code above will give you the probability that the variable will have an exact value of 5 in a normal distribution between -10 and 10 with 21 data points (meaning interval is 1). You can play around with a fixed interval value, depending on the results you want to achieve.

Comment: I think the questioner is referring to "likelihood" instead of real "probability".

Answer (score 4):

The formula cited from wikipedia mentioned in the answers cannot be used to calculate normal probabilites.  You would have to write a numerical integration approximation function using that formula in order to calculate the probability.

That formula computes the value for the probability density function.  Since the normal distribution is continuous, you have to compute an integral to get probabilities.  The wikipedia site mentions the CDF, which does not have a closed form for the normal distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, although it would fit better as a comment to the answer you are referring at: if I understand well, you aren't really _answering_ to the original question. This way, everyone will see at a first glance what you are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to say: the questioner is asking "How to calculate the likelihood of a given data point in a normal distribution given mean & standard deviation?" instead of "How to calculate probability in a normal distribution given mean & standard deviation?".

For "probability", it must be between 0 and 1, but for "likelihood", it must be non-negative (not necessarily between 0 and 1).

You could use `multivariate_normal.pdf(x, mean= mean_vec, cov=cov_matrix)` in [scipy.stats.multivariate_normal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html) to calculate it.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this program to do the math for you. Just enter in the summary statistics. No need to provide an array:

[One-Sample Z-Test for a Population Proportion:](https://gist.github.com/db5023/76f1e4d494a5b5ccb604ee03a29a0ec8)

To do this for mean rather than proportion, change the formula for z accordingly

**EDIT:**
Here is the content from the link:

```py
import scipy.stats as stats
import math

def one_sample_ztest_pop_proportion(tail, p, pbar, n, alpha):
    #Calculate test stat

    sigma = math.sqrt((p*(1-p))/(n))
    z = round((pbar - p) / sigma, 2)

    if tail == 'lower':
        pval = round(stats.norm(p, sigma).cdf(pbar),4)
        print("Results for a lower tailed z-test: ")


    elif tail == 'upper':
        pval = round(1 - stats.norm(p, sigma).cdf(pbar),4)
        print("Results for an upper tailed z-test: ")


    elif tail == 'two':
        pval = round(stats.norm(p, sigma).cdf(pbar)*2,4)
        print("Results for a two tailed z-test: ")


    #Print test results
    print("Test statistic = {}".format(z))   
    print("P-value = {}".format(pval))
    print("Confidence = {}".format(alpha))

    #Compare p-value to confidence level
    if pval <= alpha:
        print("{} <=  {}. Reject the null hypothesis.".format(pval, alpha))
    else:
        print("{} > {}. Do not reject the null hypothesis.".format(pval, alpha))


#one_sample_ztest_pop_proportion('upper', .20, .25, 400, .05)

#one_sample_ztest_pop_proportion('two', .64, .52, 100, .05)
```

Comment: While the link might provide a valuable answer, [SO asks users to post their code here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Links are useful as a reference, but they tend to break after a while, making solutions inaccessible for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the error function that's built in to the math library, as stated on their [website](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/math.html#math.erf).

Comment: Nope @user2340146, also in Python 2: https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.erf